# Is it possible to play No Man Sky offline?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I understand that No Man Sky isn't exclusively an online game other than naming planets and saving and such.

I was wondering, for PS4 or PC version, is it possible to play this offline.

For example if I'm on the road and don't have access to internet, could I play No Man Sky on my laptop whenever I want and have progress and everything save?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have read a few articles, and they all say that you are able to play No Man's Sky offline, however you cannot upload any discoveries until you connect online

[Digital Spy](http://www.digitalspy.com/gaming/ps4/feature/a801705/your-biggest-no-mans-sky-questions-answered/)

> Yes, you can play No Man's Sky offline, but all your discoveries won't be uploaded to the cloud for others to see until you go online again.

Comment: Note that you can still "upload" your discoveries without an internet connection. Earlier today, my line was physically cut by workers out on the street. I could play offline and I could "upload" my discoveries for credits. But I doubt any of that made it to the online database.

Answer (score 0):

You can disconnect to the Internet and still be able to carry on playing as you were when you were connected but the discoveries you make do not make it to the online database until you are connected to the Internet.